# What's a word for "a setting for adventure/an epic"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

It's for an RPG worldbuilding blog I'd like to make.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for some guidance on how to use this site. Our format is set up to provide a single definitive answer, which is something a naming request could almost never yield, and certainly questions about vocabulary in languages other than English are by definition off-topic.

Comment: I'd suggest you review the [synonyms for saga](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/saga).

Answer (score 1):

### [stage](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stage)

> - A platform, generally elevated, upon which show performances or other public events are given.
> - A degree of advancement in a journey; one of several portions into which a road or course is marked off; the distance between two places of rest on a road
> - *(video games)* A level; one of the sequential areas making up the game.

Consider the term "to set the stage" in a broader context than that of a theater.  Shakespeare often used this term for when narrators introduce plays.  RPGs are games of storytelling and are quite similar to plays, and they often use theatrical terms.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas to get you thinking about what works with your project:

Environment, locale, mise en scène, backdrop, curtain opening, tableau (this one has a fun plural -- tableaux), country, chessboard, playmat, gameboard, terrain, land.

Comment: Milieu. And checking a thesaurus would probably yield more.